# how to get persian letters from mysql db with php

Tags: php, utf-8, mysqli

I have a db and I've saved some persian terms like "کامپیوتر" in it. They are saved without any problem. But when I want to fetch them from db with $_GET method, they are not what I saved before and I see "?????" instead of them. I encoded all of my .php and .html to utf8 format, but the problem was not fixed.
I will appreciate if you help me fix it ...

Comment: Consult => http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/ - may even fall under a duplicate question. **Edit:** - *I was right*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- — I think it does. There's nothing specific in the question that could identify the problem, so that general end-to-end explanation is the best fit.

Comment: @Quentin You made a good call ;)